# Can one Unity Asset Bundle be used in multiple apps on the same platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have shared assets that I would like to bundle into a single asset bundle, and have that bundle be available for multiple applications on the same platform (android) for download and use.

This asset bundle would contain largely just models. Is this possible, or must the shared asset bundle be created specifically for each app that will use it? Does that change if the bundle contains more than just models?

Comment: that's actually a good question!  I for one don't know.

Comment: No you don't have to recreate asset bundle as long as it used in same platform.